# Managing layout for all devices

Tags: android

Actually i am new in android. I want to create an simple app that is able to run in all devices. The screen resolution i have selected for running my app are.

1. QVGA (240 x 320)
2. HVGA (320 x 480)
3. WVGA(800)  (480 x 800)
4. WXGA720 (720 x 1280)
5. WXGA(800) (1280 x 800)

Now i am not able to determine the name of the resources folder for all these different resolution. I have through the documentation i.e support multiple screen but i not able to create resources folder for WXGA720 (720 x 1280) and WXGA(800) (1280 x 800).

So please anyone suggest me what are the resources folder i have to create for all these resolution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You usually create resource folders for the various density and size buckets, not for the specific resolutions. Normally applications only need a couple of different layouts (e.g: phone/tablet)

Comment: can you please explain me in detail\

Comment: What kind of application are you trying to develop? A game/highly graphical one or a "normal" one? What you normally do is to specify layouts in a way that will make them automatically adjust to the users' phones

Answer (score 1):

Remember to always define your layout meassurements in dp units. I have written a blog post to help you scale your layout xml-files proportionally so you only have to define them for a single "density bucket".

http://onemanmobile.blogspot.com/2012/04/how-to-scale-your-android-layouts-to.html